# Is possible to remove an event listener in actionscript 3 (flash)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In the frame 1 of my movie, part of my code is:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
```

It works all fine, but when i go to the frame 2 the listener is still there but the function *resizeHandler* is not anymore (and i dont want it). So the console output this:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access
>   a property or method of a null object
>   reference.    at
>   index_fla::MainTimeline/resizeHandler()
>     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>     at
>   flash.display::Stage/dispatchEvent()
>     at index_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()

Is possible to remove the event listener on the frame 2? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In actionScript you can use:

```
stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
```

and that should remove your event handler.